snapcraft remove older revisions
I have one of my snap packages released in Snapcraft which have several versions that I can check with snapcraft list-revisions <snap-name>:
Rev.    Uploaded              Arches    Version    Channels
60      2024-06-17T16:15:22Z  amd64     2.13.1     latest/stable*
59      2024-05-28T16:54:26Z  amd64     2.13.1     latest/stable
58      2024-03-13T03:47:14Z  amd64     2.13.1     latest/stable
57      2024-03-06T03:52:09Z  amd64     2.13.1     latest/stable
56      2024-02-15T04:24:41Z  amd64     2.13.1     latest/stable
55      2024-02-05T03:12:04Z  amd64     2.13.1     latest/stable
54      2024-01-14T15:35:57Z  amd64     2.13.1     latest/stable
53      2023-12-01T12:51:50Z  amd64     2.13.1     latest/stable
52      2023-11-19T14:09:49Z  amd64     2.13.1     latest/stable
51      2023-09-24T13:24:42Z  amd64     2.13.1     latest/stable
50      2023-08-13T19:03:54Z  amd64     2.13.1     latest/stable
49      2023-07-30T14:55:19Z  amd64     2.13.1     latest/stable
48      2023-06-23T04:30:08Z  amd64     2.13.1     latest/stable
47      2023-06-18T14:34:34Z  amd64     2.13.1     latest/stable
46      2023-05-13T06:35:56Z  amd64     2.13.1     latest/stable

Is it possible to remove all or some of the previous revisions so that the user won't be able to install that revision of Snap? For example, I want the user to be able to install only the revision 60 of the snap. How do I do that?
